# Haskell foldl and stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

I read a posting claims `foldl` may occur stack overflow easily. And the posting sample code was:

```
maximum [1..1000000]
```

The code doesn't overflown in my machine. However it can vary by environment. I increased number like this:

```
maximum [1..1000000000]
```

it caused hard disk swapping, so I have to stop evaluation.
Sample code is not important. Is it really occur stack overflow? Or just an old days story?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Some points

- Recursive function take stack space in each call, so deeply nested calls will cause overflows
- Tail-recursive function can be optimized to iterations and therefore don't overflow
- `foldr` is **not** tail-recursive
- Lazy evaluation can prevent tail-recursive functions from being optimized
- `foldl` is tail-recursive and lazy, so it *can* overflow
- `foldl'` is tail-recursive and strict, so it's safe

Comment: But the bonus with foldr is it can produce partial results as it operates on infinite lists.

Answer (score 3):

Data.List.maximum is implemented using the lazy `foldl1`.  There is a rule to use `strictMaximum` (implemented using the strict `foldl1'`) if the list contains `Int` or `Integer`.

So, the following program compiled with optimisations does not cause a stack overflow:

> main = print $ maximum [1..1000000000 ]