# How is foldl lazy?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

There are lots of [good questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977417/haskell-foldl-and-stack-overflow) about `foldl`, `foldr`, and `foldl'` in Haskell.

So now I know that:
1) `foldl` is lazy
2) don't use `foldl` because it can blow up the stack
3) use `foldl'` instead because it is strict ([ish](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27))

How `foldl` is evaluated:
1) a whole bunch of thunks are created
2) after Haskell is done creating thunks, the thunks are reduced
3) overflow the stack if there are too many thunks

What I'm confused about:
1) why does reduction have to occur after all thunk-ing?
2) why isn't `foldl` evaluated just like `foldl'`?  Is this just an implementation side-effect?
3) from the [definition](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27), `foldl` looks like it could be evaluated efficiently using tail-recursion -- how can I tell whether a function will actually be efficiently evaluated?  It seems like I have to start worrying about order-of-evaluation in Haskell, if I don't want my program to crash.

Thanks in advance.  I don't know if my understanding of the evaluation of `foldl` is right -- please suggest corrections if necessary.

---

UPDATE:  it looks the answer to my question has something to do with Normal Form, Weak Normal Form, and Head Normal Form, and Haskell's implementation of them.
However, I'm still looking for an example where evaluating the combining function more eagerly would lead to a different result (either a crash or unnecessary evaluation).

Comment: `foldl` _is_ tail-recursive... but it turns out that in Haskell (unlike in eager languages) tail-recursion is a bad thing.

Comment: @Daniel -- good point, I wrote that incorrectly and have edited the question to correct that.  Also, thanks for clarifying that -- I had always thought of tail-recursion as unquestionably a good thing.

Comment: @DanielWagner [Bang patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) to the rescue! Tail-recursion can still be a good thing in Haskell.

Comment: @DanBurton Yep, you bet. If you use the eager fragment of Haskell, then of course tail recursion is good there, too!

Comment: @DanielWagner Tail-recursion is a bad thing in Haskell? Why?

Comment: @MasterMastic Generally the way to get tail recursion is to have an accumulator. Combine this with laziness, and what you get by the time you make all the recursive calls is an accumulator with a very deeply-nested thunk. Boom! Stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, that by definition:

```
foldl op start (x1:x2:...:xN:[]) = ((start `op` x1) `op` x2) ...
```

the line in foldl that does this is:

```
foldl op a (x:xs) = foldl op (a `op` x) xs
```

You are right that this is tail recursive, but observe that the expression

```
(a `op` x)
```

is lazy and at the end of the list, a huge expression will have been build that is then reduced.
The difference to foldl' is just that the expression above is forced to evaluate in every recursion, so at the end you have a value in weak head normal form.

Comment: So `op` is more lazy than `foldl`?  I guess it seems to me that there are multiple possible lazy evaluation orders for `foldl`, and that Haskell picks the worst one.  I will read up on this 'weak head normal form' and hopefully it'll make more sense.

Comment: To preserve semantics, foldl must indeed assume that op is lazy. See the link in hammar's answer, it is explained very well there. BTW, Haskell picks not the worst one but the correct-in-all-cases one.

Comment: Okay, it's making more sense.  But what do you mean by 'correct-in-all-cases'?  That Haskell will not evaluate computations that are not used later?

Comment: Exactly. For, when it did that, the semantics of the program would change. Consider, for example, that (42, undefined) is a perfect tuple. Haskell programs must not crash by evaluating the second component before it is absolutely needed.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that in `foldl f`, it's not necessarily the case that `f` is strict, so it might be too eager to reduce the thunks up front. However, in practice it usually is, so you nearly always want to be using `foldl'`.

I wrote [a more in-depth explanation of how the evaluation order of `foldl` and `foldl'` works on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form/6889335#6889335). It's rather long but I think it should clarify things a bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm still looking for an example where evaluating the combining function more eagerly would lead to a different result

The general rule of thumb is never, ever use `foldl`. Always use `foldl'`, **except when you should use `foldr`.** I think you know enough about `foldl` to understand why it should be avoided.

*See also: [Real World Haskell > Functional Programming # Left folds, laziness, and space leaks](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#id594142)*

However, your question neglects `foldr`. The nifty thing about `foldr` is that it can produce incremental results, while `foldl'` needs to traverse the entire list before yielding an answer. This means that `foldr`'s laziness allows it to work with infinite lists. There are also questions and answers that go into detail about this sort of thing.

Having brought that up, let me try to succinctly answer your questions.

> 1) why does reduction have to occur after all thunk-ing?

Reduction *only* occurs at strictness points. Performing IO, for example, is a strictness point. `foldl'` uses `seq` to add an additional strictness point that `foldl` does not have.

> 2) why isn't foldl evaluated just like foldl'? Is this just an implementation side-effect?

Because of the additional strictness point in `foldl'`

> 3) from the definition, foldl looks like a tail-recursive function to me -- how can I tell whether a function will actually be efficiently evaluated? It seems like I have to start worrying about order-of-evaluation in Haskell, if I don't want my program to crash.

You need to learn a little bit more about lazy evaluation. Lazy evaluation is not exclusive to Haskell, but Haskell is one of the very, very few languages in which laziness is the default. For a beginner, just remember to always use `foldl'` and you should be fine.

If laziness actually gets you into trouble someday, that is when you should probably make sure you understand laziness and Haskell's strictness points. You might say that said theoretical day is a strictness point for lazy-by-default learning.

*See also: [PLAI > Part III: Laziness](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/)*

Comment: I didn't mention `foldr` because, in general, it's not equivalent.  But +1 for mentioning strictness points (is that an actual technical term?  the series of pipes and tubes have failed me).

Comment: I thought that I picked it up from PLAI, but glancing over it again, perhaps not. I guess I got the term from the college class where we studied PLAI. It seemed like a very natural and technical term to use; I'm surprised it is not more widespread. I'm going to take the liberty of creating a SO question about it and see if we can come up with some good explanations.

Comment: Asked: [SO: What are Haskell's strictness points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490768/what-are-haskells-strictness-points)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like I have to start worrying about order-of-evaluation in Haskell, if I don't want my program to crash.

In my opinion, the best options if you want your program not to crash are (ranked from better to worse in terms of yield per effort spent):
1. Give it enough resources.
2. Improve your algorithm.
3. Do micro-optimisations (one of which is `foldl'`).

So, rather that worrying about the *order* of evaluation I'd rather first worry about *what* is to be evaluated (is `foldr` enough? can I do without folding that at all?). And before that, I'd increase the available stack space.

You don't limit your whole program to 8MB of RAM, do you? Why would you limit the stack space then? Just increase the stack space to 4GB and start worrying when something really hogs a lot of it (like you do with heap memory).

And to somewhat answer the question of how `foldl` is lazy:

```
foldl (\x y -> y) undefined [undefined, 8] -- evaluates to 8
foldl' (\x y -> y) undefined [undefined, 8] -- fails to evaluate
```

Comment: The example is there not to prove the laziness of `foldl`, but to demonstrate a situation when the laziness is needed.

Comment: -1 for proposing that you ignore obvious performance failures. Give it enough resources is a _user_ solution, not a _programmer_ solution.

Comment: @monadic, using lists at all is most of the time an obvious performance failure, yet that is often acceptable and even embraced.

Comment: @Rotsor not really. Lists have different performance characteristics than an array but not necessarily bad. For example, front-append O(1) is great. Don't spread FUD...

Comment: @monadic, one can do amortized O(1) front-append with arrays that is much faster than using linked lists. Persistent structures are a convenience coming at a cost! The same way laziness is. So, if you call "lists are bad" FUD, I call "laziness is bad" FUD.

Comment: @Rotsor When did I insult laziness? Its just that a medium is necessary. Amortized O(1) front-append with arrays doesn't exist in haskell without ST because you would have to copy the array every time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3639/discussion-between-rotsor-and-monadic)