# Performance of list concatenation implemented as a left fold

Tags: performance, list, haskell, time-complexity, lazy-evaluation

Consider list concatenation implemented as a fold left, that is, `foldl (++) []`.
What is the complexity of this implementation in a lazy-evaluated language, such as Haskell?
I understand that in a strict language the performance is quadratic in the total number of elements, but what happens when laziness is involved?

I've tried to evaluate by hand the expression `([1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]) ++ [7,8,9]` (which corresponds to `foldl (++) [] [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`)
and it seems that we traverse only once each element, but I'm not sure whether my reasoning is correct:

```
([1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]) ++ [7,8,9]
= { rewrite expression in prefix notation }
(++) ((++) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]) [7,8,9]
= { the first (++) operation needs to pattern match on its first argument; so it evaluates the first argument, which pattern matches on [1,2,3] }
(++) (case [1,2,3] of {[] -> [4,5,6]; x:xs' -> x:(++) xs' [4,5,6]}) [7,8,9]
= { x = 1, xs' = [2,3] }
(++) (1:(++) [2,3] [4,5,6]) [7,8,9]
= { the first (++) operation can now pattern match on its first argument }
1:([2,3] ++ [4,5,6]) ++ [7,8,9]
```

I have assumed the following implementation of `(++)`:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
xs ++ ys = case xs of [] -> ys
                      (x:xs') -> x : (xs' ++ ys)
```

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered by [How is foldl lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487455/how-is-foldl-lazy) Specifically, `foldl` has an impact on performance because of laziness.

Comment: Compare also to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294658/11732: if you don't insist on forming the list first and scanning it after it, you only pay the concatenation price once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say we have `([1,2,3]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9]`

```
([1,2,3]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9]
(1:([2,3]++[4,5,6))++[7,8,9]
1:(([2,3]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9])
1:((2:([3]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9])
1:2:(([3]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9])
1:2:(3:([]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9])
1:2:3:(([]++[4,5,6])++[7,8,9])
1:2:3:([4,5,6]++[7,8,9])
1:2:3:4:([5,6] ++ [7,8,9])
1:2:3:4:5:([6] ++ [7,8,9])
1:2:3:4:5:6:([] ++ [7,8,9])
1:2:3:4:5:6:[7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Notice how every element in the first list had to be moved twice? That's because it was two from the end. In general if we have `(((a1++a2)++a3)++..an)` each element in the list `ai` will have to be moved `n-i` times.

So, if you want the whole list, it's quadratic. If you want the first element, and you have `n` lists, it's `n-1`* operations (we need to do the step-case of `++` `n` times). If you want the `i`th element, it's the number of operations for all the elements before it, plus `k-1`, where it was in the `k`th list, counting from the end.

*Plus the `n` operations from `foldl` itself, if we want to be pedantic

Comment: Thanks! That's spot on. Meanwhile, I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/474311), whose first half also responds to my question.